# CancellationToken Registered Delegate Not Getting Called

Tags: c#

An async method takes a CancellationToken and registers a delegate with it. It then passes that token to Task.Delay and awaits. When the token is cancelled the registered delegate is never run. If we do not pass the cancellation token to Task.Delay then the delegate is run. What is going on? All the docs and articles I can find say registered delegates are guaranteed to run.

This is happening .Net Framework 4.7.2 and 4.8. Also in .Net 6.
In .Net 7 it works as expected.

[Fiddle link](https://dotnetfiddle.net/3scpA1)

Edit 1:
With some more investigation I can see that the callback is getting unregistered by the using block before the task that will run it has executed. I guess this means callbacks can happen at any time relative to the cancellation taking effect and if you need them to run you would have to run them yourself if you are going to dispose the registration. Please inform me of a better way...

```
using System;
using System.Threading;
using System.Threading.Tasks;

public class Foo
{
    public async Task Run(CancellationToken ct)
    {
        using (ct.Register(this.OnCancel))
        {
#if true
            // OnCancel is not called
            await Task.Delay(100, ct).ConfigureAwait(false);
#else
            // OnCancel is called
            await Task.Delay(100).ConfigureAwait(false);
            ct.ThrowIfCancellationRequested();
#endif  
        }
    }

    private void OnCancel()
    {
        Console.WriteLine("OnCancel()");
    }
}

public class Program
{
    public static void Main()
    {
        MainAsync().GetAwaiter().GetResult();
    }

    private static async Task MainAsync()
    {
        try
        {
            var cts = new CancellationTokenSource();
            var foo = new Foo();
            cts.CancelAfter(10);
            await foo.Run(cts.Token).ConfigureAwait(false);
        }
        catch (OperationCanceledException)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Cancel exception caught");
        }
        
        // Give time for any uncompleted tasks to run before exiting
        await Task.Delay(300).ConfigureAwait(false);
    }
}
```

Comment: The right approach is dependent on what exactly you want to achieve with the registration. For example, adorning tasks with a `.ContinueWith(..., TaskContinuationOptions.OnlyOnCanceled)` is another way to get something to run after cancellation. If you want to use a registration on the `CancellationToken` then yes, you ideally need to know the scope of the token, or if that's really not feasible you could dispose the registration in the handler itself by keeping it around as a member.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This behavior is the result of two interplaying (and AFAIK undocumented) implementation details:

1. Cancellation token callbacks are all executed (synchronously) one at a time from within the call to `Cancel`.
2. [`await` resumes executing synchronously](https://blog.stephencleary.com/2012/12/dont-block-in-asynchronous-code.html), so if a task completion occurs, the `async` method continuation can execute on that same stack. (Link is to my blog).

So, consider how `Run` executes:

- The callback is registered.
- `Delay` is invoked which registers *another* callback and then returns an incomplete task.

Later, when the cancellation token is completed, it executes its callbacks ([in reverse order](https://github.com/dotnet/runtime/blob/adfccb13c3cb52083d794b3a95fc50b2c914eda4/src/libraries/System.Private.CoreLib/src/System/Threading/CancellationTokenSource.cs#L720-L721)):

- The last callback is executed first. This cancels (completes) the `Task.Delay` task.
- The task completion triggers *its* continuations, i.e., the `await` continues executing.
- The `Run` method continues executing, evaluating the `await` and raising an `OperationCompletedException`.
- The `using` in the `Run` method is executed, un-registering the other cancellation token callback. Note that this callback is un-registered *from within the other callback.*

What's more interesting to me is that .NET 7 changes this behavior. I'm not sure if there's a [trampoline being hit](https://devblogs.microsoft.com/pfxteam/when-executesynchronously-doesnt-execute-synchronously/?WT.mc_id=DT-MVP-5000058) preventing the `await` continuation from executing synchronously, or if there's a race condition somewhere, or what.

Comment: Thank you so much. This is really helpful to wrap my head around how things can legitimately behave like this.